# how do i print an element from a 2 dimension array-list?

Tags: java, arraylist, printing, 2d

The last command should print "printcat" but it does not. Why is that?

```
ArrayList<String[]> outerArr = new ArrayList<String[]>();    
String[] myString1= {"hey","hey","hey","hey"};  
outerArr .add(myString1);
String[] myString2= {"you","printcat","you","you"};
outerArr .add(myString2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outerArr.get(1)));
System.out.println(outerArr.get(1).get(1));
```

Comment: The compile error probably tells you why—you can call `get()` on a `List`, but not on an array.

Comment: What does it actually print?  Does it report an error?
You may also want to add the java tag.

Comment: A list is not the same as an ArrayList? It gives no error it just does nothing.

Comment: If you didn't get an error, then you didn't compile the code you posted. The code you posted won't compile.

Comment: Ok, why wont i compile?

Comment: If you want answers about your question, post your real code and what it really does. Otherwise you'll get answers about other things. Also, I just noticed that you're not clear on what an *array* is. An array is not an `ArrayList`, it's a type like `String[]` in your example. An `ArrayList` is a type of `List`.

Comment: This was the real code and it did nothing. I am clear on what an Array is and what an Arraylist is. In this case your asumptions were wrong cause the question was clear ( in my opinion) and the awnser also. but thx for thinking with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a two dimensional Array-List. It's Just an Array-List which contains arrays of Strings as data.
You can use `System.out.println(outerArr.get(1)[1]);` to get the result.

`outerArr.get(1)` will return `String[]`, which is `{"you","printcat","you","you"}`, and then you can use `outerArr.get(1)[1]`, which will return the "printcat" element at the 1st index.

Answer (score 0):

`List`, `ArrayList` and array (`[]`) are all different things (though the first two are related, and they all are kind of similar things). if you want something in 2D, it means you use something 2 times. for example a 2D `List` would look like `List<List<String>>` and a 2D array would look like `String[][]`. what you have is a list of arrays, which is not a 2D array, nor a 2D list. what you most likely want is `List<List<String>> outerArr = new ArrayList<List<String>>();`. The rest you should figure out yourself.

Comment: ok thx i try. An example would be nice if you find the time and will. but thx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out! Because the Arraylist exists of Array you must handle the Array as a normal Array. So this works fine.

```
System.out.println(outerArr.get(1)[1]);
```